# Remove migration in Entity Framework core 2

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

Why `remove-migration` apply migrations instead of removing unapplied migrations as expected!?

```
PM> remove-migration
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\badr\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[100403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.0.0-rtm-26452 initialized 'DataContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[200101]
      Executed DbCommand (5ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'__EFMigrationsHistory');
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[200101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'__EFMigrationsHistory');
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[200101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [MigrationId], [ProductVersion]
      FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory]
      ORDER BY [MigrationId];
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[200402]
      Applying migration '20170920100825_Empty'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[200101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO [__EFMigrationsHistory] ([MigrationId], [ProductVersion])
      VALUES (N'20170920100825_Empty', N'2.0.0-rtm-26452');
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[100403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.0.0-rtm-26452 initialized 'DataContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[200101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'__EFMigrationsHistory');
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[200101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [MigrationId], [ProductVersion]
      FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory]
      ORDER BY [MigrationId];
The migration '20170920100825_Empty' has already been applied to the database. Revert it and try again. If the migration has been applied to other databases, consider reverting its changes using a new migration.
```

Comment: Do you have `Migrate()` being called in your Startup class?

Comment: @Smit yes, I have  `dataContext.Database.Migrate();` in Startup class

Comment: Follow this guide for upgrade. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/
EF Core tools needs to initialize service provider to get the db context. Application startup needs the same but code should be refactored in a way that EF Core tools don't run the app in the process hence ends up migrating the db.

Comment: @Smit but this project was initially created using .NET core 2!!

Comment: Can you share your startup & program classes? If you are following Asp.NET core 2.0 startup pattern then you can easily refactor the code so that EF tools doesn't run application and migrate the db.